# Determining if a product is taxable or imported

Tags: object-oriented, ruby, finance

This should tell me whether the product is taxable or imported. Name should indicate if the product is imported or certain keywords should tell that the product is non-taxable (chocolates, book, pills).

Could you please review the following class products?

```
class Product
  NON_TAXABLE = [/chocolates/, /book/, /pills/]

  def initialize(product_name)
    @product_name = product_name
  end

  def is_taxable?
    taxable = false
    NON_TAXABLE.each { |x| taxable = x.match(@product_name) if taxable }
    !taxable
  end

  def is_imported?
    /imported/.match(@product_name)
  end
end
```

Answer (score 5):

Your `is_taxable?` function code does not seem to work. The issue is that `taxable` is never going to be true, so you'll never assign a new value. You want to write `if !taxable` instead. Your code becomes:

```
def is_taxable?
    taxable = false
    NON_TAXABLE.each { |x| taxable = x.match(@product_name) if !taxable }
    !taxable
end
```

It's still possible to make it simpler using Ruby functions on arrays.

```
def is_taxable?
  NON_TAXABLE.none? { |x| x.match(@product_name) }
end
```

This means: if my product is not among the tax-free products, then it is taxable.

Comment: I got confused many times by the "double not logic" (a taxable product is not is non taxable list) and by Ruby  double not, but this should be a correct answer now.

Comment: you can drop `!!`, a successful match is a truish value.

Comment: Yeah, but I would expect is_taxable? to return `true` or `false`, not a partial match or `false`. I don't know what's idiomatic in Ruby though.

Comment: It's definetely idiomatic to return only true/false for a `method?`. But I was talking about the  `!!` in the block, `Enumerable#none?` will always return a boolean no matter what.

Comment: Right, updated.

Answer (score 0):

If you change the `NON_TAXABLE` constant from a bunch of regular expressions to one big regular expression to rule them all, like this:

```
NON_TAXABLE_RE = Regexp.union(%w(chocolates books pills))
```

Then the `is_taxable?` method (I prefer `taxable?`) would look like this:

```
def is_taxable?
  not NON_TAXABLE_RE.match(@product_name) #I like the explicit 'not'
end
```